# Using Replicate Function with Conditional Argument in R

Tags: r

very recent beginner with R here. I'm trying to create multiple Random Variables Z using two random numbers stemming from U(0,1), and I'm having trouble with using the replicate function when Z has conditional arguments.

Here is what I am working on:

Generate two random numbers U<sub>1</sub> and U<sub>2</sub> Set the following:

V<sub>1</sub>=2U<sub>1</sub> - 1

V<sub>2</sub>=2U<sub>2</sub> -1

S = (V<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>) + (V<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>)

That part would be simple, but what trips me up is this part:

If S>1, start over, otherwise,

Z<sub>1</sub>= sqrt((-2*ln(S))/(S)) *V<sub>1</sub>

Z<sub>2</sub>= sqrt((-2*ln[S])/(S)) *V<sub>2</sub>

And I'm to replicate those 500x each. I've in the past, I didn't have conditions such as the S>1 above and would just use `replicate(n, function(Z))` but now I am not sure how to include the condition of S<1.

Please don't hesitate to ask for clarification, as I probably overcomplicated this a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a function like this:

```
f <- function(N, mult=2) {

    S <- NULL
    while (length(S) < N) { 
        mult <- mult * 2
        nm <- N * mult
        V1= 2 * runif(nm) - 1
        V2= 2 * runif(nm) -1
        S = V1^2 + V2^2
        i <- S > 1
        S <- S[i]
    }
    cat("mult is", mult, "\n")
    V1 <- V1[i][1:N]
    V2 <- V2[i][1:N]
    S <- S[1:N] 

    # note that I added the abs to avoid taking the sqrt of a negative number
    # you probably have a better way to avoid that
    Z1= sqrt(abs((-2*log(S))/(S))) *V1
    Z2= sqrt(abs((-2*log(S))/(S))) *V2
    cbind(Z1, Z2)
}

 set.seed(0)
 result <- f(500)
# mult is 4 
head(result)
#              Z1         Z2
#[1,]  0.84399240 -0.2401726
#[2,] -0.38290136  0.6071211
#[3,] -0.09405977  0.3436486
#[4,]  0.20980731  1.0566666
#[5,]  0.86480486 -0.1319527
#[6,] -0.54518219 -0.5629898
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work, will need to look over it a little more to fully understand its reasoning (haha). I'm curious, if "result" is the encompassment of 1000 of the variables, how would I go about representing them on a QQ plot? It leaves the "Error in sort(y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default" message, but perhaps I am just implementing the command wrong.

Comment: Responding to myself: Assuming just >qqplot(result, result)